# ADSL with static IP address?

Tags: isp, adsl

I would like to know which ISPs offer DSL/ADSL service with static ip address?
It doesn't matter if it is for home or business users, if you know some just name it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What country are you interested in?

Comment: The world is a very big place - and this is a global site, so you really do need to be more specific.

Comment: what country are you in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Thinkbroadband's advanced search](http://www.thinkbroadband.com/search/package/advanced.html) feature lets you specify a static IP address assignment as one of the filters.

Answer (score 1):

Any ISP that serves business users should offer static IPs at an extra charge. This is a standard business service.

ex...

Verizon
Qwest
AT&T
Bell*

... etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, I personally use [Enta.net](http://www.enta.net) who provide a variety of ADSL/SDSL services and static IPs (single or multiple). Enta also provide "known limit" packages (i.e. you can transfer 90Gb per month "at peak hours" [8am to 8pm] and 300Gb off peak) whereas the other static IP provider I was with - [Demon Internet](http://www.demon.net) - offered "unlimited" usage, but if you happened to use more than 60Gb per month, you were ratelimited to around 32Kbp/s!

[Andrew and Arnold](http://www.aaisp.net/) are another provider I'm aware of which offers static IPs (Enta and A+A both also offer IPv6 connections: I don't know about Demon now)

Answer (score 0):

Verizon offers Business ADSL that offers you a static IP at an added cost:

- For $39.99/month you can get it in 3 MBPS or 7.1 MBPS with a [dynamic IP](http://smallbusiness.verizon.com/products/internet/hsi_pricing.aspx#dynamic).
- For $79.99/month you can get it in 3 MBPS with a [static IP](http://smallbusiness.verizon.com/products/internet/hsi_pricing.aspx#static).
- For $149.99/month (or $199.99/month) you can get it in 7.1 MBPS with a [static IP](http://smallbusiness.verizon.com/products/internet/hsi_pricing.aspx#static).

Answer (score 0):

[PlusNet](http://www.plus.net/support/service/policies/IP_block_allocation.shtml) allows a static IP for free, the better (ie more expensive) products even let you have multiple IPs, though I think they stop at a /28.

Answer (score 0):

[Imagine](http://www.imagine.ie)

Answer (score 0):

In India it is Tatabroadband, Reliance and Airtel is offering this service.